# FOS user bundle doesn't keep logged session

Tags: php, symfony, docker

I have integrated the FOS user bundle just as the quick guide tells you to do. it seem to work except that once I log in and redirects it loses the session for some reason and I'm back as anonymous user.

This is what i get when I log in before I'm redirect back:
[image]

As you can see I'm successfully logged in and should be redirect to the homepage. However when I'm on the homepage I'm redirected back to the login because I check if the user is logged in or not. So somehow it does not remember that I logged in.

This is my configuration for security.xml

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
    # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory: ~
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                check_path: /login_check
                login_path: /login
                provider: fos_userbundle
                default_target_path: /
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

config.yml

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: UserBundle\Entity\User
```

I obviously added the bundle to the app kernel and created the user entity. when i run the doctrine command it successfully creates the user table, etc...

I have this working fine in another project, the only difference is that for this project I'm using docker. Would this cause a problem?

Edit:
This is the code I use to check if the user is logged in:

```
if(!$this->container->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY') ){
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('fos_user_security_login'));
        }
```

And the toolbar shows me as anonymous after the login_check redirects.

[image]

Comment: Can we see the code you use "to check if the user is logged in or not" ? Also what does the debug toolbar tells you after the redirect ? Do you still have your username displayed ?

Comment: @Glukose I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was brought to my attention that if my`save_path` is under `/var/www/project` which is mounted on my local machine it would not work.

So in config.yml I commented out the `handler_id` and changed the`save_path` value to `~`